# Return NULLS in FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I am querying data from CRM 2011 using FetchXML to build a report in SSRS 2008. My query works, but it won't return records that link to a entity that is null. This is my Query:

```
<fetch>
      <entity name="appointment">
        <attribute name="scheduledstart" />
        <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="ownerid">
            <attribute name="firstname" alias="ownerFirstName" />
            <attribute name="lastname" alias="ownerLastName" />
        </link-entity>
        <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="new_contactperson">
            <attribute name="parentcustomerid" alias="parentaccount" />
            <attribute name="new_businessunit" alias="businessunit" />
        </link-entity>
        <attribute name="new_contactperson" />
        <attribute name="subject" />
        <attribute name="new_coldernotes" />
    <link-entity name="activityparty" from="activityid" to="activityid">
    <attribute name="participationtypemask" alias="participationtypemask" />
        <filter>
        <condition attribute="participationtypemask" operator="eq" value="9" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="partyid">
            <attribute name="fullname" />
        </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="scheduledstart" operator="on-or-after" value="@FromDate" />
            <condition attribute="scheduledstart" operator="on-or-before" value="@ToDate" />
        </filter>
      </entity>
</fetch>
```

So for example, where it links to the systemuser or contact, if those records are null the appointment record doesn't return. Is there away to return records even if it's linked to a null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to add link-type="outer".